# How can I stop the bass from shaking my house?

Tags: walls, ceiling, speakers

When I play music through my speakers, they are on top of a shelf directly under the ceiling, and the bass shakes the wood panel wall and ceiling tiles, which causes loud rattling. Is there some simple fix to this, maybe to weigh these things down somehow, that will lower the amount of rattling?

The wood panel walls are very thin, about half an inch (?).

I'd want a very cheap solution.

Sorry if this isn't an appropriate question here... I couldn't find any other forum for this.

Comment: Neither wall panels nor ceiling tiles should be loose enough to rattle in the first place.  I'm guessing you don't want to go to the expense of fixing the root cause here, so -- turn down the bass.  Placement (assuming you don't have some [redacted] Bose901s) will not change the coupling much, so moving the speakers is unlikely to help.

Comment: Do you have any kind of isolation between the woofer and the shelf?

Comment: @BrownRedHawk the speakers sit on the shelves

Comment: Try putting the speakers on a towel or piece of foam. Your problem *might* be the direct coupling between speaker cabinet and shelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there aren't easy and/or cheap ways to weigh down the paneling or ceiling.

I'm going to suspect that a healthy majority of the rattle is not from the sound vibrations in the air, but from the physical motion/vibration transferring from the woofer through the shelf, to the  floor, wall, and ceiling. Isolating the woofers on something like memory foam or similar to isolate to vibrations may somewhat lessen the transfer.

Unfortunately, all loud sound systems deal with this to some extent. If isolating the woofers is not enough, then reducing the hard surface areas would be the next step. Hanging framed art, tapestries, etc on the walls all helps to dampen the transfer of sound waves to the walls.